# Cancel executing query in SQL via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I know how to cancel a SQL Command in C# (command.Cancel()) but now I have the following code executing a SQL script which takes a longer time. I want that the user can cancel this process but don't know how to do this.

```
  string file = File.ReadAllText(workingDir + @"\" + fileName);

        // execute
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);

        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(file);
```

Is there a method or something to stop that? I haven't found one yet and Cancel does not work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't there a Cancel() method on server.ConnectionContext? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.cancel(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Oh. Ok, I tried server.Cancel(). Sorry for that. Didn't know that I had to cancel the ConnectionContext method. Thank you!

Comment: By the way: How to call that from another class? When I try class.server.ConnectionContext.Cancel() he does not recognize "server"

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create a public or internal property at the class level for the server variable. Just make sure to handle disposal/cleanup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to kill the process same like how user kills from SSMS use the below.

```
server.KillProcess(server.ConnectionContext.ProcessID);
```

Comment: How to call this from another class? He does not recognize 'server'

Comment: I am note sure about your code arrangement. Somehow other class needs to have reference to this class. To kill a process we need the valid connected Server object and processId.

Comment: It's just a cancel button on a "Please Wait" form. When the user presses this button then it should just call the method above but it doesn't work somehow...

Comment: Are you getting any exception when calling the KillProcess or you are not able to call the KillProcess. Just make the server variable as static and call it to make sure the mechanism works. Later beautify the code to avoid static.

Comment: I solved it! I could not invoke it. I used methodinvoker now and finally it can call it. Thanks for your help!